# text turning into a liquid problem

Tags: mesh, fluid-simulation, text-object, shrinkwrap, palettes

I want to transform a caption into a waterfall, but I can't.

I tried in 2 ways:

1. The words become liquid, but for some reason, a letter or two does not become liquid, and I have no idea why. I haven't done anything different with those letters than the rest. All letters are meshes.
2. I tried to turn the letters into a different shape (using shrinkwrap) which then the new shape turns into a liquid, but the shape does not turn into a liquid even after applying a shape key, I guess it is because the letters do not form a complete shape and the liquid option does not work on a broken shape.

If anyone explains why a certain letter didn't turn into a liquid, or if there is a way to turn letters into a complete shape, I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Did your caption/text into a mesh object before allowing it to become a liquid Geometry Inflow?   You might also find that -- if your text isn't very large -- you'll have to spend time playing with particle sizes.

Here's an example for you to study:  [image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. my text was already a mash, but increasing the resolution and making the text bigger solved the problem. I really appreciate the advice.